# Replace or update a specific value in a table using SQLite Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, crud

The situation is that I have a table with more than 200 columns and I want to update specific values in one record without update the entire row of that record.

I was researching a while but I can't find somthing like that.

I'm using:
SQLite.net-PCL 3.1.1
SQLitenetExtensions 1.3.0
VS Community 2017
in a crossplatform projec in Xamarin Forms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any basic SQL tutorial will show you how to use an UPDATE to this.

Comment: Using SQLite with Xamarin forms should really be separated via MVVC; whereas your SQLite functionality should be handled as a model for your view controller. Really, as Tim pointed out, you should look into how to work SQLite updates, or use LINQ in your model (since we are using c#)

Comment: The tutorials that I did see, update the entire row, I need to update only specific values in a single row, not the entire row. If you have something to help me I going to be very grateful.

Comment: You may have to refine your search criteria. try http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlupdate.php it shows you how to update one specific field. but you will probably have to extrapolate to suit your specific use case.